# compact and convex set question

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I have been working on this problem and have not been able to find a solution.  I am having trouble just getting started on this problem so any ideas would be helpful.

For a compact and convex subset of the plane,

(a) Prove that given any direction, there exists a line that is parallel to that direction that divides the set into equal areas.

(b) Prove that there are two perpendicular lines that divide the set into four equal areas.

Any help with this problem would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to parametrize the cutting of the set by parallel lines as a function from closed interval giving the ratio of the corresponding areas. Show that the function is continuous and hence must attain the value corresponding to ratio 1 : 1.